# See History of Notifications, in Ventura (vs Big Sur, Monterrey...)

Tags: notifications, ventura

In versions of OSX before Ventura, clicking (or double clicking?) the time would display the history of notifications including notifications you had already seen or dismissed.  Now in Ventura, this brings up the `Notification Center` but it does not seem to keep the full history (or any real history) of notifications.

Is there any way to see the history of all notifications?  Just to be clear, these aren't missing notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I might have fixed this myself by simply changing my notifications from "banner" to "announcement" or something like that. It keeps them on the screen until I dismiss them.